# Selenium chrome driver --headless Как использовать свои куки?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Актуально** - весь интернет проштудировал в RU сегменте и ничего не нашёл(

Как использовать куки (надстройки) своего браузера (который установлен на компьютере) ?

Если убираю `--headless` всё прекрасно работает.

А с `--headless` браузер не получает профиль.

Проще говоря, мне нужно в `headless` режиме, подгрузить пользовательский профиль или хоть что то, что бы я был авторизован на тех сайтах, на которых авторизовался через браузер компьютера.

```
private void ZapuskBrauzera()
{

    ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
    option.AddArgument("--headless --window-size=1920x1080");
    option.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\1\");

    var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

    Browser = new ChromeDriver(driverService, option);
}
```

Comment: Судя по https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=775911 и https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=617931, headless режим просто не умеет загружать профиль.

Comment: @PashaPash, 1. BackstopJS при использовании headless хрома может подставлять куки через кастомные скрипты. 2. В коде в вопросе ошибка с указанием профиля: _`user-data-dir`_ - должно быть `--user-data-dir`, а ещё, есть вероятность, что там нужна пара кавычек, т. к. путь содержит пробелы. 3. Я не понимаю, почему 3 параметра добавляются 2 вызовами `AddArgument`. 4. Чтобы вероятность ответа увеличилась, чтоит сделать [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Такое поведение сейчас не предусмотрено. Иначе говоря, это невозможно. Chrome никогда не читает и не пишет в профиль, если он запущен в режиме без окна.

Если когда-нибудь ситуация изменится, то [это будет отмечено в #617931](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=617931).

Comment: На Windows 10 все нормально работает, на Windows Server 2012 нет

Answer (score 0):

В режиме **—headless** надо использовать [Chrome devtools](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/). С помощью него вы получите доступ почти ко всему функционалу браузера.

Comment: но это не отвечает на вопрос как(?). можно использовать C# и  вы получите доступ почти ко всему функционалу ОС. Это отвечает на вопрос как получить список файлов в ОС?

Comment: Chrome devtools protocol, который я упомянул выше позволяет коннектиться к браузеру с запущенным debug и выполнять любые действия. Исходный вопрос касался именно управления браузером через selenium.